# How to generate a random number based on the time of the day?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, random

I am simulating an Iot Device (Noise Sensor) in Azure IoT hub the code below works perfectly fine.
However I want to simulate something closer to reality, where I can use different decibel ranges between different hours.

Something like this:

```
if 00.00- 7.00AM - Randum number between (10-20)
if 7am-9AM - Random number  between (20-40)
if 11.30-1.30pm Random number between 60-80
```

I dont want to create a lof of IFs,Elses, as I would like to have cleaner code.

How should I do this in a structured manner?

My code below: (only the relevant method)

```cs
private static async Task SendDeviceToCloudMessagesAsync(CancellationToken ct)
{
    // Initial telemetry values
    int minNoise = 20;
    int maxNoise = 90;
    var rand = new Random();
    
    while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        double noiseDecibels = rand.Next(minNoise, maxNoise);
                  
        // Create JSON message
        string messageBody = JsonSerializer.Serialize(
            new
            {
                eui= "58A0CB0000101DB6",
                DecibelValue = noiseDecibels
            });
        using var message = new Message(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(messageBody))
        {
            ContentType = "application/json",
            ContentEncoding = "utf-8",
        };
    
        // Add a custom application property to the message.
        // An IoT hub can filter on these properties without 
        // access to the message body.
        message.Properties.Add("noiseAlert", (noiseDecibels > 70) ? "true" : "false");
    
        // Send the telemetry message
        await s_deviceClient.SendEventAsync(message);
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now} > Sending message: {messageBody}");
    
        await Task.Delay(60000);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to have something with specific criteria, you will have to have if/else statements to meet that criteria, no alternative way unfortunately, you could create a function to return the decibel value based on the time which would help keep it "cleaner"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm approaching this question in a data structure pattern (like you asked) so i would create a RangeHourDictionary class inheriting from Dictionary.

The `Add` method will add the ranges where the key will represent the start time and end time. The values will be an array of int of the size of 2 where the first value will represent the start range and the second value will be the end of the range.

Another function will be `GetRandomRange` which will get the current time and will return the value (which again, will represent the start and end of the random range)

```
public class RangeDictionary : Dictionary<Range, int[]>
{
   public void Add(TimeSpan from, TimeSpan to, int[] randomValues)
   {
      Add(new Range(from, to), randomValues);
   }

   public int[] GetRandomRange(TimeSpan now)
   {
       try
       {
            return this.First(x => x.Key.From < now && x.Key.To > now).Value;
       }
       catch
       {
            return null;
       }
    }
}

public struct Range
{
     public Range(TimeSpan from, TimeSpan to) : this()
     {
          From = from;
          To = to;
      }
      public TimeSpan From { get; }
      public TimeSpan To { get; }
 }


//initialize

 var lookup = new RangeDictionary();
 lookup.Add(new TimeSpan(07, 0, 0), new TimeSpan(09, 0, 0), new int[2] { 10, 20 });
 lookup.Add(new TimeSpan(09, 30, 0), new TimeSpan(11, 0, 0), new int[2] { 40, 50 });
 lookup.Add(new TimeSpan(11, 0, 0), new TimeSpan(13, 0, 0), new int[2] { 60, 80 });


// call GetRandomRange

 var res = lookup.GetRandomRange(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay);
 if (res != null){
    Random random = new Random();
    var randomValue = random.Next(res[0], res[1]);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have such specific conditions, the only way is to manually check, which of them applies.

```
private Random randomGenerator = new Random();



function decibel(DateTime d) {
  int randMin = 0, randMax = 0; //the interval for the random value
  var t = d.TimeOfDay;

  if (t.TotalHours < 7)  //0:00 - 6:59:59 
  {
    randMin = 10; randMax = 20;
  }
  else if (d.TotalHours < 9)  //7:00 - 8:59:59 
  {
    randMin = 20; randMax = 40;
  }
  else if (d.TotalHours >= 11.5 && d.TotalHours < 13.5) //11:30 - 13:29:59
  {
    randMin = 60; randMax = 80;
  }
  ...


  // returns a rand with:  randMin <= rand < randMax
  return randomGenerator.Next(randMin, randMax);
}
```